# How to declare a java.util.Set as entry parameter of {m:template}

Tags: m2doc

I have a m2doc docx template to generate a Word document from my eclipseRCP application.

I would like to declare a java.util.Set objet as an entry parameter of a {m:template}.

My code is the following :

`{m:template t_templateTest(req:request::Request, filters: Set)}`

I've got this error message :

`{m:template   <--- missing classifier literalt_templateTest(req:request::Request, filters: Set)}  <---Expression "filters" is invalid: missing classifier literal`

I don't know how to declare the classifier for the Set.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

AQL only support Sequence and OrderedSet and not all collection types you can find in OCL. The definition of an OrderSet also need to define what type of elements will be contained inside it, for instance:

```
OrderedSet(String)
```

You can have a look at the [type syntax of the AQL documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/documentation/#Typeliterals) for more details.